# How to migrate to Websockets from Comet Processor in Apache tomcat 8.5 onwards?

Tags: websocket, migration, tomcat8, comet, java-websocket

Apache tomcat 8.5 onwards Comet support is deprecated and as per them we can migrate to websockets.
In my application we had used comet processor for streaming events to client when client make a simple HTTP GET request and establish a connection.
But now since Comet is not supported , we have to migrate to Websockets keeping backward compatibility in mind.
We can keep the same earlier URLs as endpoint. 
But the client application need to update the code at their end to use HTML5 features.
Is there any way we can keep the client code same? Or the client applications need to update acordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Websockets servers must have onMessage, onError, onOpen, onClose methods. Websocket clients must have onMessage callback method. I recommend getting javax.websocket implementation. Here is a good intro: http://enterprisewebbook.com/ch8_websockets.html